# Standard way of updating row in laravel view in custom table

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Im fetching a table data from controller in blade view and then using custom made table, im binding the rows with the data fetched from the controller. Now, is it ok to map the edit button of the row with the id which is primary key in the table or is there any standard way of updating, modifying or deleting the row so that the id is hidden from the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is ok depends on the level of confidentiality of the id. If there is any danger that the id would be misused by hackers or the id can be misused in any other means, resulting in a leak of confidential data or a problem in data integrity, then it is not ok.

If it is not ok, then you might want to generate a hash based on the id and some other data. In this case you would encode the data and decode it. If the data will have a life cycle, like a time interval, then you might want to include the current time as an input of the hash and upon decoding validate whether the hash is still valid.

Read this article for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: what is the standard method that is used by already available frameworks for table view in laravel ?

Comment: @kapsid standard method for what purpose? For hashing?